# Sub-Query or Join with embedded/nested document using C# LINQ with MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to do something like bellow example but getting exception as -
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 ' cannot be used for parameter of type  'System.Linq.IQueryable`1' of method.
Here is my code and related classes . how can i resolve this issue, is there any way except which a trying to do.

```
    var channels = _channelService.Collection;
    var tracks = _trackService.Collection;

    var query = from b in tracks.AsQueryable()
                select b;

    var data = (from q in channels.AsQueryable()
               from p in q.Episodes
               //from x in  trackcoll.AsQueryable()
               select new
               {
                   p,
                   Tracks = query.Where(w => p.Tracks.Contains(w.Id))
               }).ToList();

// Related classes
    public class ContentBase : IAuditable
    {
        public string Id { get; set ; }
        public string CreatedBy { get ; set ; }
        public string CreatedOn { get ; set ; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get ; set ; }
        public string UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    }

    public class Channel: ContentBase
    {
        public List<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Episode: ContentBase
    {
        // List of track Id
        public List<string> Tracks { get; set; }
    }
    public class Track: ContentBase
    {
        public string TrackUrl { get; set; }
        public string Duration { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set;

    }
```

Comment: can you add your c# classes (channel,track,episode) to the question?

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ Please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB's LINQ support for joins is limited to equal joins as described [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/reference/driver/crud/linq/). Your expression cannot be translated into Aggregation Framework's [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) since there's no equivalent syntax for `.Contains()`.

Therefore you have to run an operation that's closer to Aggregation Framework syntax. One example is a fluent aggregate interface which allows you to run extension methods having the same name as Aggregation Framework's operators. Try:

```
var q = _channels.Aggregate()
                    .Unwind(x => x.Episodes)
                    .Lookup(
                        foreignCollectionName:"tracks", 
                        localField:"Episodes.Tracks", 
                        foreignField:"_id", 
                        @as:"Tracks");

var result = q.ToList();
```

Above code will return a `List<BsonDocument>`

Comment: I am just trying to join or make an sub-query with embedded child document

Comment: @KhairulAlam modified my answer

Answer (score 2):

mickl's answer will get you there with the official driver, but if you don't like dealing with bsondocuments and would like to have some degree of type-safety, you can simply do the following with **mongodb.entities** library (which i'm the author of):

```cs
    public class EpisodeWithTracks
    {
        public Track[] Tracks { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
var pipeline = new Template<Channel, EpisodeWithTracks>(@"
[
    {
        $unwind: '$<Episodes>'
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: '<track_collection>',
            localField: '<Episodes.Tracks>',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: '<Tracks>'
        }
    }
]")

.Path(c => c.Episodes)
.Tag("track_collection", collectionName)
.Path(c => c.Episodes[0].Tracks)
.PathOfResult(ewt => ewt.Tracks);

var result = DB.Aggregate(pipeline)
               .ToList();
```

here's the [wiki page](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/wiki/13.-String-Templates) explaining how it works.

Comment: Error: Channel can not be used as type parameter T

Comment: @Khairul Alam when using the library all root entities must inherit from 'Entity' class. please see the wiki for documentation.

Comment: @KhairulAlam here's a working example: https://gist.github.com/dj-nitehawk/15279dbfeaa8807ff48f75a4e28b9b62